# How can I remove the "Shop" word from WooCommerce Breadcrumbs?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The Breadcrumbs in WooCommerce 3 is :

Home > Shop > Product Cats... > Product name

So, how can I remove the "Shop" word from Breadcrumbs ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing something similar

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', array($this, 'rewriteBreadcrumb') );

public function rewriteBreadcrumb($crumbs) {
    global $post;

    $breadcrumbSize = sizeof($crumbs);

    // You can edit the breadcrumb array here
    if( $breadcrumbSize > 1 ) {
        $crumbs[$breadcrumbSize-1][0] = $customCrumbName;            
    }

    return $crumbs;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you can use this plugin...

[Woocommerce Permalinks Manager](https://premmerce.com/woocommerce-permalink-manager-remove-shop-product-product-category-url/)

... to remove "Shop" from the slug.